# Get user owned courses with a Laravel relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I need to get all the courses that the user owns with a for each loop in my view.
I tried to set up a relationship that way:
User.php

```
public function user_courses() {
        return $this->hasMany(User_Course::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

Course.php

```
public function user_course() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User_Course::class);
}
```

User_Course.php

```
class User_Course extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function course(){
        return $this->hasOne(Course::class,'id');
    }

}
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
@foreach($user->user_courses as $course)
        {{  dd($course)  }}
                <div class="course-flex-item">  
                    <div class="course-header">
                        <strong>{{ $course['title'] }}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-description">

                    </div>
                    <div class="continue-button">
                        <button>Continue</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img class="course-image" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png" alt="fasdf">
                        <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: %;background-color: #f64c71;font-family:'Montserrat';font-weight:bold">
                        <span class="">%</span>
                 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
```

This is what the dd($course) returns:

```
App\User_Course {#1232 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "user__courses"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "user_id" => 2
    "course_id" => 2
    "progress" => "40"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

Im trying to get each course detail via the course_id.
for example if a user with the id of 3 owns a course with the course_id of 2, the database row will look like this:
id|user_id|course_id
1 |    3  |   2

If you need more code, tell me in the comments.

users migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->id(); $table->string('name'); $table->string('email')->unique(); $table->string('username')->unique(); $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); $table->string('password'); $table->rememberToken(); $table->timestamps(); });
```

courses migration:

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('color')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

user__courses migration:

```
Schema::create('user__courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
            $table->text('progress')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
```

Comment: `$course->load('course')` and you will get all details

Comment: @V-K it returns this in the dd:
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "course" => null
  ]

Comment: please add DB migrations for all models

Comment: @V-K that's what you need?

Comment: update your question, do not do it in comments

Comment: oh ok ill add it

Comment: @V-K now, that's okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:
inside user model you need to create this function

```
     public function courses()
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'user_courses','user_id','course_id');
      }
```

Comment: And then, how I get the course details in the view? @ali

Comment: this function will give you access to the course details

Comment: try it and tell me if you have any question

Comment: So $user->courses() should give me all the user course details?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#1022 ▼
  #table: "user_courses"
  #foreignPivotKey: "user_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "course_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "courses"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotWhereNulls: []
  #pivotValues: []
  +withTimestamps: false
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null
  #accessor: "pivot"
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1234 ▶}
  #parent: App\User {#1021 ▶}
  #related: App\Course {#1177 ▶}
}

Comment: ?? and how i implement it in the foreach?

Comment: without the braces ()